# What is the right way to use the option PlotLegends and "Expressions"

Tags: plotting

How do I plot the graph of `x^2,x^4`, in the same graph for `x` in `[-5,5]`.

```
PlotRange->{-5,20},PlotLegends-> "Expressions"].
```

I thought the input would be

```
Plot[{Sin[x^2],Sin[x^4]},{x,-5,5},PlotRange-> {-5,20}, PlotLegends-> "Expressions"]
```

Comment: `Plot[{x^2, x^4}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {-5, 20}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

Comment: What is the problem with `Plot[{Sin[x^2],Sin[x^4]},{x,-5,5},PlotRange-> {-5,20}, PlotLegends-> "Expressions"] `, it works fine.